# Angular.js features inside Node.js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a node.js app which has been developed over a few weeks time. I want to add certain features like infinite-scroll for which the packages in node.js require angular.js as well. So, I thought that I would go ahead and add angular.js support as well, so that that one page(and others  which need such support) can be served through angular.js pages.

Going through the basic examples available over the Internet, I created a listAll.jade file(as I use express-jade) in the /views directory. Here is how it looks like:

```
    html(ng-app='demoapp')
  head
    title List All Entries!
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js')
    script(src='js/listAllEntries.js')
  body(ng-controller='GetAllEntries')
    div(ng-repeat='post in posts')
      | {{post}}
```

And then inside /public/js directory, I added a listAllEntries.js file, Here are the its contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var angular = require("angular");
var app = angular.module('geniuses', []);

app.controller('GetAllGeniuses', [
'$scope',
function($scope){
 // $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
 console.log("Here?...")
 $scope.posts = [
  'post 1',
  'post 2',
  'post 3',
  'post 4',
  'post 5'
];
}]);
```

And lastly, to wire them together, in the index.js file(I have renamed app.js to index.js) I did this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/listAllEntries',function(req, res){
    res.render('listAllEntries', {});
});
```

But, when I hit http://localhost:3001/listAllEntries, all I get is {post}} on the browser. The console.log statement added in the .js file doesn't get printed so I am assuming that the js file isn't being loaded.

I have looked at almost all the options and queries but couldn't really resolve this.

Comment: is this the actual code or pseudocode? because your app and controller are named totally different things in those two files. in the jade you have `ng-app='demoapp'` and `ng-controller='GetAllEntries'`, but in the JavaScript, the `app` is `geniuses` and the `controller` is `GetAllGeniuses`.

Comment: Oops yeah there were some issues there. It's demo code so apologies for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular isn't an isomorphic framework at this time (although Angular 2 is intended to be). So, for now, you can't `require('angular')` and render Angular templates in the server.

Instead, you can serve an html file (`*.jade`) that includes (a) the Angular framework and (b) your Angular app via a regular script tags. When this html file is loaded in the browser, the browser run your Angular code, and you will see the `console.log`.

To get posts for your Angular app, you will need to use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) server to access your backend API (your express app). The API should serve JSON, which your Angular app will then parse out and add to its model (`$scope.posts`).

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the reply. It was informative. I was under the impression that require("angular") would work. So I searched around and changed the upper and lowest block of js code to this: (function (angular) {}(angular).. That loaded the posts on the browser.. Also, a bit off topic, but I am a hardcore backend developer but I am developing this app for a close friend of mine.. So  I am a newbee as far as front end technologies go :)